# How to convert the following to a sort function without item getter, lamda or pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what i have so far, I know itemgetter is the faster way to sort but i forgot how to make the changes back to the sort() function.

```
import csv

mfl = []
prl = []
sdl = []

with open("ManufacturerList.csv") as manlist:
    ml = csv.reader(manlist)
for line in ml:
    mfl.append(line)

with open("PriceList.csv") as pricelist:
    pl = csv.reader(pricelist)
for line in pl:
    prl.append(line)

with open("ServiceDatesList.csv") as sdlist:
    sl = csv.reader(sdlist)
for line in sl:
    sdl.append(line)

#need to use a sort function instead of item getter
new_mfl = (sorted(mfl, key=itemgetter(0)))
new_prl = (sorted(prl, key=itemgetter(0)))
new_sdl = (sorted(sdl, key=itemgetter(0)))


for x in range(0, len(new_mfl)):
    new_mfl[x].append(prl[x][1])
```

Comment: are you looking for inplace sort -> `new_mfl.sort(key=itemgetter(0))` ?

Comment: im looking to sort it witout itemgetter. I know i have to create a dictionary i just dont remember how, field_name = ['item_id', 'item_name', 'item_type', 'item_price', 'service_date', 'status']


class ItemInventory:

    def __init__(self, item_id, item_name, item_type, item_price, service_date, status):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_type = item_type
        self.item_price = item_price
        self.service_date = service_date
        self.status = status            is what i am using